# Выведение 2х массивов из одного по ключам

Tags: php

Ребята , есть проблема, создаю форму обратной связи и проблемы с валидацией, точнее как, все дело в том, что у меня массив с ошибками(которые выводятся) создается при помощи массива с правилами и массива с данными, а я хочу что бы массив с данным тоже создавался и данные в него записывались только в том случае, если проходят валидацию.
Как-то так, надеюсь понятно объяснил.

```
<?php
require 'validation.php';

session_start ();
if (isset ($_SESSION['uspeh'])){
    echo "Uspeh";
    unset($_SESSION['uspeh']);
}

        function dimon($dima){
            if (isset($_POST[$dima]))
                echo $_POST[$dima];
        }

        if(isset($_POST) && isset ($_POST['button'])) {
            $data = [
                "firstname" => $_POST['firstname'],
                "lastname" => $_POST['lastname'],
                "email" => $_POST['email'],
                "number" => $_POST['number'],
                "comment" => $_POST['comment']
            ];

            $rules = [
                'firstname' => 'is_alpha_dash|required',
                'lastname' => 'is_alpha_dash|required',
                'email' => 'is_email|required',
                'number' => 'is_phone_number|required',
                'comment' => 'required',

            ];

            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $data [$key] = test_input($value);
            }

            $errors = validate($data, $rules);


            if (!$errors) {

                $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a+');
                fputcsv($fp, $data, ',');
                fclose($fp);

                $_SESSION['uspeh'] = true;

                header('Location: http://localhost/test.php');
            }

        }
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<form method="post" action="" class="form">

    <br>
    <label for="firstname"><span class="formText"></span> Имя:</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Имя"  value="<?php dimon('firstname');?>"/></br>
    <span class="error"> <?php if(isset($errors['firstname'])) echo $errors['firstname'];?> </span>
<p>
    <label for="lastname"><span class="formText"></span> Фамилия:</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Фамилия"  value="<?php dimon('lastname');?>" /></br>
    <span class="error"> <?php if(isset($errors['lastname'])) echo $errors['lastname'];?></span>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="text"><span class="formText"></span> Email:</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"  value="<?php dimon('email');?>" /></br>
    <span class="error"> <?php if(isset($errors['email'])) echo $errors['email'];?></span>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="number"><span class="formText"></span> Номер телефона:</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number" placeholder="8**********" value="<?php dimon('number');?>" ></br>
    <span class="error"> <?php if(isset($errors['number'])) echo $errors['number'];?></span>
</p>
<label for="comment"><span class="formText"></span> Отзыв покупателя:</label></br>
<textarea rows="10" name="comment" id="comment"><?php dimon('comment');?></textarea></br>
    <span class="error"> <?php if(isset($errors['comment'])) echo $errors['comment'];?></span></br>
<input type="submit" name="button" value=" Отправить " />

</form>
```

Валидатор:

```
<?php

        function required ($value) {
            if($value){
                return '';
            } else {
                return 'Поле должно быть заполнено';
            }
        }
        function is_alpha_dash ($value){
            if(preg_match("/^[а-яёА-ЯЁa-zA-Z ]{3,16}$/u", $value)) {
                return '';
            } else {
                return 'Некорректные данные';
            }
        }
        function is_email ($value){
            if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                return '';
            } else {
                return 'Некорректный e-mail';
            }
        }
        function is_phone_number ($value)
        {
            if (preg_match("/^(\s*)?(\+)?([- _():=+]?\d[- _():=+]?){10,14}(\s*)?$/", $value)) {
                return '';
            } else {
                return 'Некорректный номер';
            }
        }


  /**
     * @param array $data
     * @param array $rules
     * @return array
     */
        function validate (array $data, array $rules) {
            $errors = [];

            foreach ($rules as $key => $rule) {
                $error = validate_field($data[$key], $rule, $data);
                if ($error) {
                    $errors[$key] = $error;
                }
            }
            return $errors;
        }
    /**
     * @param $value из массива data
     * @param $rule строка с правилами из значения масива rules
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
        function validate_field ($value, $rule, array $data = [])
        {
            $rule = parse_rule($rule);
            $errors = [];
            foreach ($rule as $validator => $args) {
                $vargs = array_merge([$value, $data], $args);
                if (call_user_func_array($validator, $vargs)) { // Вызывает callback-функцию с массивом параметров
                    $errors = call_user_func_array($validator, $vargs);
                }
            }
            return $errors;

        }

            /**
             * @param $rule
             * @return array
             */
            function parse_rule($rule)
            {
                $rule = !$rule ? [] : $rule; // если рулл пустой , то он становится пустым масивом, иначе это строка с правилами

                if (is_array($rule)) {
                    return $rule;
                }

                $result = [];
                $rules = explode('|', $rule); //  Разбивает строку с помощью разделителя

                foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                    $frags = explode(':', $rule);

                    $name = $frags[0];
                    $args = isset($frags[1]) ? explode(',', $frags[1]) : [];

                    $result[$name] = $args;
                }


                return $result;
                }


                    function test_input($data)
                    {
                        $data = trim($data); //возвращает строку с удалёнными пробелами
                        $data = stripslashes($data); //удаление обратного слеша
                        $data = htmlspecialchars($data); //преобразует спец символы в html
                        return $data;
                    }


?>
```

Comment: Не понятно. Покажите что формируется, как формируется и что хочется

Comment: Нужно чтобы из массив data формировался на основе массива rules и данные в него записывались, только если прошли валидацию.